# Ubuntu boot fails on Lenovo P52 Thinkpad when hybrid display is set in BIOS

Tags: boot, nvidia, devices, bios, thinkpad

Booting to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS fails when the display is set to 'hybrid' in the BIOS (using Nvidia driver 415) When I switch to 'discrete', then it boots to Ubuntu OK. Because I am dual booting with Windows, it's annoying having to change this setting when I change OS. My laptop is a [Lenovo Thinkpad P52](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p52-type-20m9-20ma?linkTrack=Homepage:Body_Search%20Products&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=P52%20(Type%2020M9,%2020MA)%20Laptop%20(ThinkPad)), with both an integrated Intel graphics adapter, [plus an NVIDIA Quadro P3200](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/tp_p52_hmm_en.pdf).

Comment: Does this occur with a supported version of Ubuntu? Ubuntu dropped support for 12.04.5 last year as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases .

Comment: Do you mean 12.04 or 18.04?

Comment: I'm seeing similar symptoms on a P52 with ubuntu 16.04 desktop and using the hdmi port